# Массив, вывод в несколько label

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, вывод

Не получается заменить содержимое в четырёх label содержимым массива

```js
const вопросыОсновнойМассив = [
{вопрос: "Вопрос 1",
варианты: ["Вариант1.1", "Вариант1.2", "Вариант1.3", "Вариант1.4",],
правильныйОтвет: 2,},
{вопрос: "Вопрос 2",
варианты: ["Вариант2.1", "Вариант2.2", "Вариант2.3", "Вариант2.4"],
правильныйОтвет: 1,}
];
let НомерТекущегоВопроса=0;

function показатьВарианты(){
    for (одинОтвет of вопросыОсновнойМассив[НомерТекущегоВопроса]['варианты']) {
    document.querySelector('.варики').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.варики').innerHTML + '<label> <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="cheese" />Варик</label>'.replace('Варик', одинОтвет);
    }
};
показатьВарианты();
```

```html
<div class="варики">  
     <label> 
          <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="cheese" />Варик 
     </label>
     <label> 
         <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="cheese" />Варик 
     </label>
     <label> 
         <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="cheese" />Варик 
     </label>
      <label> 
         <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="cheese" />Варик 
     </label>

</div>
```

Comment: какой должен быть итог, напишите. не очень ясно чего вы пытаетесь добиться

Comment: Выводиться должен один из под массивов в зависимости от номера текущего вопроса.

Comment: код в ответе ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        question: "Вопрос 1",
        variants: ["Вариант1.1", "Вариант1.2", "Вариант1.3", "Вариант1.4"],
        rightAnswer: 2
    },
    {
        question: "Вопрос 2",
        variants: ["Вариант2.1", "Вариант2.2", "Вариант2.3", "Вариант2.4"],
        rightAnswer: 1
    }
]

const wrapper = document.querySelector('.variants')
wrapper.innerHTML = getAnswers(2)

function getAnswers(question) {
    return arr
        .filter((el, idx) => idx === (question - 1))
        .map(el => {
            return el.variants
                .map(el => {
                    return `<label>
                        <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="cheese" />${el}
                    </label>`
                })
                .join('')
        })
        .join('')
}
```

```html
<div class="variants">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" />Варик
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" />Варик
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" />Варик
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" />Варик
    </label>
</div>
```